# How to change a link-image on mouseover in this unusual setting?

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of pictures as links on one site, like this:

```
<A HREF="web/contact.html"><IMG SRC="img/contact2.png" class="mobile" border="0" alt="Contact"></a>
```

Later on, I position and size them correctly with CSS, and added a hover effect:

```
    .mobile{
    position: absolute;
    left: 69%;
    top: -12%;
    width: 19%;
    height: auto;
    transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: 993; }

    .mobile {
        position:absolute;
        top: -11%;
        left: 68%;
        width:23%;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
        transition: linear;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

So far, so good, works as intended, but what if, instead of simply resizing it and slightly changing it's position, I want it to display a different image on mouseover?

I tried doing it like this:

```
    <A HREF="web/contact.html" class="mobile" border="0" alt="Contact"></a>
```

with this CSS

```
    .mobile
    {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("img/contact2.png") center top no-repeat;
    width: 23.2%;
    height: auto;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0%;
    transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: 992; }


    .mobile:hover {
        position:absolute;
        background-image: url('img/contact3.png');
        top: -3%;
        left: 11%;
        width:26%;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
        transition: linear;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

But that just results in the image disappearing altogether. What am I doing wrong? I think it has something to do with the use of % for size, especially the "height: auto", but because of the context of the rest of the site, I can't replace that. 
If you need any more info, just let me know, I didn't wanna spam you guys with more than necessary.

Below I will once copy-paste the entire code, since I realize that with the minimal info I gave last time, my problems couldn't really be answered. Maybe with this, someone can copy it and see what I mean:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=800" />

        <title>Mainsite</title>

     </head>

    <body style="padding:0px; margin:0px; overflow: scroll;" >
    <body background="http://i.imgur.com/YAxp4xz.jpg">
    <style>
    html,body { height:100%; }
    </style>


    <div class="text">

     <style>
           @font-face {
        font-family: 'gt-walsheim';
        src: url('web/gt-walsheim.ttf');
    }
        </style>

         <style type="text/css">
        .prozent {line-height: 150%;
         font-family: "gt-walsheim";
        }
      </style>


    <br>
      <p class="prozent" align="center">
       <font size="+3.5"><b><font color="#804040">RESTAURANT-NAME</font></b>                                  </font>
        <br>
        <br>
        <font size="+2"><font color="#804040">Blablablablablabla Über uns         balbalba ablab balbal Willkommen ablabla blabal
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>         




    </div>
    <!-- Ende dv class="text" -->



    <div class='box'>
            <div class='content'>

            <div class="tisch">

    <A HREF="web/menü.html"><IMG SRC="http://i.imgur.com/QebCkyE.png" class="menu" border="0" alt="Zur Speisekarte"></a>

    <IMG SRC="http://i.imgur.com/qoHQ9Bd.gif" class="teller" border="0" alt="">

    <A HREF="web/contact.html"><IMG SRC="http://i.imgur.com/WNR18gb.png" class="handy" border="0" alt="Kontakt"></a>

    <A HREF="web/zeiten.html"><IMG SRC="http://i.imgur.com/I4GTdXr.png" class="pad" border="0" width="47%" alt="Öffnungszeiten"></a>



    </div>
    <!-- Ende tisch -->






            </div>
    </div>

    <style>

    .text {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 990; }

    .box{
            position: relative;

            width: 100%;                /* desired width */
    }
    .box:before{
            content: "";
            display: block;
            padding-top: 35%;         /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
    }

    .content{
            position:  absolute;


            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
    }


    .tisch
    {
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;


    <!-- x% höhe von alles -->

    width: 100%;
    z-index: 991; }

    .menu
    {
    position: absolute;
    width: 23.2%;
    height: auto;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0%;
    transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: 992; }

    .menu:hover {
        position:absolute;
        top: -3%;
        left: 11%;
        width:26%;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
        transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
        z-index:999;
    }



    .teller
    {
    position: absolute;
    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    left: 30%;
    top: 0%;
    z-index: 992; }

    .handy
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 69%;
    top: -17%;
    width: 19%;
    height: auto;
        transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: 993; }

    .handy:hover {
        position:absolute;
        top: -15%;
        left: 68%;
        width:23%;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
            transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
        z-index:999;
    }

    .pad
    {
    position: absolute;
    left: 78%;
    top: 48%;
    width: 12%;
    height: auto;
        transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: 993; }

    .pad:hover {
        position:absolute;
        top: 43%;
        left: 76%;
        width:14%;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
            transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
        z-index:999;}

    </style>
```

Those are of course all placeholder graphics, but that's not important-
What I want it to be able to not only transition in size and position, but to an entirely different image as well. 
You may notice that everything is defined with %, and works just fine. This (and all those divs) are necessary as a setup, so no matter how I resize the window, the pictures not only stay proportional to it, but also in position to each other. 
Not quite sure while changing that the picture source is defined in the stylesheet, instead of in the link itself, causes problems and makes my pictures disappear.

Comment: I fixed the typo, but that wasn't actually the problem, I made that typo because I changed the foreign words that were originally in there, when I wrote down my question.

Comment: Why in your html code you dont have any element with class mobile?

Answer (score 0):

This definition doesn't work for 2 reasons. First, a block level element is only as tall as the contents inside. Without contents inside, it is 0 height. So this element doesn't appear on the page because it is 0 height. Second issue is you're using `background-image` wrong. What you meant to do there is use `background`, the short-hand property, since you're including `center top no-repeat`.

```
.mobile
    {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-image: url("img/contact2.png") center top no-repeat;
    width: 23.2%;
    height: auto;
    left: 10%;
    top: 0%;
    transition: linear;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: 992; }
```

Besides the issues I just mentioned, this definition doesn't work because you misspelled "mobile"

```
.moblile:hover {
        position:absolute;
        background-image: url('img/contact3.png');
        top: -3%;
        left: 11%;
        width:26%;
        height:auto;
        display:block;
        transition: linear;
        transition-duration: 0.5s;
        z-index:999;
    }
```

If you address those issues, it works.

```css
html,body {height:100%;}
.mobile {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg") center top no-repeat;
  width: 23.2%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 0%;
  transition: linear;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 992;
}

.mobile:hover {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg');
  top: -3%;
  left: 11%;
  width: 26%;
  display: block;
  transition: linear;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<A HREF="web/contact.html" class="mobile" border="0" alt="Contact"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply. The typo in "mobile" was actually not in the original code, I didn't want to include the foreign words that are actually in there, so I changed it when copying the code, and that's when the typo happened. The picture doesn't disappear now, but it crops heavily. In my original attempt (which could only resize and reposition), I get the full image, but only at a certain % of its original size. In your solution, I only get an (oversized) corner. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: @Phil the div element and the background image need to have the same aspect ratio, or the same size, loosely speaking. They either need to be the same size, or the same aspect ratio in combination with `background-size: cover;` for the background image to resize itself to try and fit the aspect ratio of the div element without cropping/clipping any of the image. But you didn't include any images in your post, so I can't tell you what size your div needs to be or a way to get the background image to totally show or show properly.

Comment: I'm very sorry for any confusion, this is my first time posting here and I didn't want to overload my question with too much detail. Tomorrow I will add the image and some information what my endgoal is, but right now, I noticed something. You added a height in px to the properties. For what I'm doing, I think I absolutely need to limit myself to % heights. In my original attempt, that worked out quite well, but as soon as I delete your "px-height" and leave only "%-height/width", the entire picture disappears again.Is there some way to keep working with only %based proportions?

Comment: @Phil sure, percentage based heights work fine. The point is, *the div needs a height*. If the % height wasn't working, it means the % value isn't giving the div a height - which has nothing to do with the background image. In my example, the .mobile element wouldn't work with 100% height because 100% refers to 100% of the container, and in this case, the container is `body` and body will only be as tall as the content inside of it. Since `.mobile` is the only element in body, and there is no text or anything in `.mobile`, body's height is 0. 100% of 0 is 0.

Comment: @Phil so I updated my example to tell body/html to be 100% height (which makes them 100% height of the viewport), then set `.mobile { height: 100%; }` and you can see the background image.

Comment: @Phil the trick to getting the background image to show and not be clipped is to give the element a height/width that match the dimensions of the background image, and use `background-size` to fit the image to the parent as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the patient explanation. I realize I haven't given you enough information about the context. It's already very late where I live, but tomorrow, i'll upload the entire context. Then you'll see where my problem actually comes from. It'll also give me the chance to look over this once again, maybe i'll find out where I made a stupid mistake, before bothering you with it :)

Comment: I edited my question to include the entire code, with uploaded images. I hope this is okay, otherwise i'll delete it. I also restated my question.

Comment: @Phil when I hover over any of the 3 images, it zooms them in and transitions their position. What isn't working or what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Everything about this is exactly what I wanted to happen. But now I've tried to also change the image, when I hover over it. (For example, to an open menu-card) And that's what I can't seem to get right. I know how it usually works, but if I attempt that method, the pictures aren't displayed anymore. That's what I tried to explain yesterday, but of course you didn't have enough info to see that.

Comment: @Phil Oh. Well if you assign a `background-image` to the element, and swap that on hover, then the element needs a specified height. The background image doesn't take up any space in the element it's applied to. It only displays as much as the element is visible. So the element needs to match the size of the image, or at least the aspect ratio, and then you can use something like `background-size: cover;`. This is basically the same thing as I've already explained. Seems to me like you don't understand how background images work?

Comment: @Phil look at this as an example. The image is 500x376. Try messing around with the height and width and see if you can figure it out. And notice how if you don't declare a height, the background disappears - becauase the element then has 0 height. The background image in the element won't force the element to be any sort of size. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xgrLvX

Comment: @Micael-coker You might be right, maybe I don't understand it. Because if I set a height/width in pixels (or anything other than %), the picture won't scale if I resize the window. For example, I added height/width in the correct aspect ratio, added background-size: cover;, and it works and looks fine...until I make the window smaller. Now the one picture I tried this with stays the same size, instead of shrinking with the window, as it does in the code-setup i have right now.

Comment: @Phil sure it will, if you use relative units for the parent so that it scales with the window and `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: 100% 100%;` or some relative background-size value so that it scales with the element it's applied to. And then you can always do cool stuff like always have the height match an aspect ratio by finding a percentage based way to assign high to match an aspect ratio. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ndgadq